# Move letters to the most right possible

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I will have one string mixed with dots and lowercase letters like:

```
string = '..a..d..h.w';
```

I want it to have all letters moved to the most right possible:

```
result = '.......adhw';
```

I would really appreciate a short solution for this ;)

---

I was trying to use regex:

```
result = string.replace(/(\.)|(.)/g,'$1$2');
```

But without luck, it remains the same.

Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 3):

You could strip all of the dots and then strip all of the non-dots and concatenate them :

```
var output = input.replace(/[^\.]/g,'') + input.replace(/\./g,'');
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple string manipulation for this could be string.count('.')*'.'+string.replace('.','')

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
var str = '..a..d..h.w';
var result = ("..........." + str.replace(/\./g, '')).slice(-str.length);
```